# Creating Soap API request from apex

Tags: apex, soap-api

I have used Partner WSDL and created an apex class. I am trying to connect to force.com to get the records. I just started this as an example to get familiar with the SOAP API.

I actually want to use the SOAP API to create and delete the UserTerritory records. I need SOAP API for this because DML on UserTerritory are not supported in apex.

As a start I have created the snippet to get some records using the API, but I am getting an error

> Web service callout failed: Unable to parse callout response. Apex type not found for element Name

Code Snippet:

```
partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap partner = new partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap();
partner.endpoint_x = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/39.0';

partnerSoapSforceCom.LoginResult lr = partner.login('UserName', 'Password' + 'SecurityToken');
partnerSoapSforceCom.SessionHeader_element header = new 
partnerSoapSforceCom.SessionHeader_element();
header.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
partner.SessionHeader=header;
partnerSoapSforceCom.QueryResult qr = partner.query('Select Id, Name from Account limit 1');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that the Partner API WSDL contains features that the native version of wsdl2apex doesn't support.

In particular, the problem here with you example code is the `any` element on the dynamic sObject complexType.

```
<complexType name="sObject">
    <sequence>
        <element name="type"               type="xsd:string"/>
        <element name="fieldsToNull"       type="xsd:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <element name="Id"                 type="tns:ID" nillable="true" />
        <any namespace="##targetNamespace" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

Basically, an `sObject` can have any number of additional fields defined in the result. WebServiceCallout.invoke doesn't know how to handle that. See [Supported WSDL Features](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm#supported_wsdls_topic-title).

---

As a proof on concept for the API call test, just try omitting the `Name` from the SOQL query. E.g.

```
partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap partner = new partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap();
partner.endpoint_x = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/Soap/u/39.0';

partnerSoapSforceCom.SessionHeader_element header = new partnerSoapSforceCom.SessionHeader_element();
header.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
partner.SessionHeader=header;
partnerSoapSforceCom.QueryResult qr = partner.query('Select Id from Account limit 1');
```

Comment: When i updated the query I am getting the Id's. But that is just to start using the partnerSoapSforceCom. With your help now I am able to create and delete the User Territory records. Thanks!! @Daniel Ballinger